# A method only throwing an exception depending on whether param is true or false. Bad programming?

Tags: php, oop

Straight to the point.

```
interface DispatcherInterface {

    /**
     * @param RouteInterface $route
     * @return ResponseInterface
     * @throws InvalidRouteException
     */
    public function dispatch(RouteInterface $route);

}
```

As you can see the method above throws an `InvalidRouteException` because it verifies that the controller exists, the action exists in the controller class etc.

I then needed to make the internal method below public:

```
/**
 * @param RouteInterface $route
 * @throws InvalidRouteException
 */
private function verifyRoute(RouteInterface $route);
```

So now in the application I can do:

```
$route = $this->router->route( $request->getUri() );

try { 
    $this->dispatcher->verifyRoute($route);
    // Check if the user has access to this page/controller/action
    $response = $this->dispatcher->dispatch($route);
}
catch(InvalidRouteException $ex) {
    // Error 404
}
```

Since the route has already been verified the `dispatch(RouteInterface $route)` method no longer needs to run the `verifyRoute(RouteInterface $route)` method so therefore no `InvalidRouteException` will be thrown.

I want the `dispatch(RouteInterface $route)` method to have the option in the API to verify the supplied route or skip the verification part.

The method would become:

```
/**
 * @param RouteInterface $route
 * @param bool $verifyRoute
 * @return ResponseInterface
 * @throws InvalidRouteException if $verifyRoute = true
 */
public function dispatch(RouteInterface $route, $verifyRoute);
```

I don't think I have ever seen something like:

```
@throws InvalidRouteException if $verifyRoute = true
```

In API documentation before so I am a bit unsure as to whether this is bad programming?

If I remember correctly in Java a method either throws an exception or it does not, there is no in between so that adds to my scepticism about what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

> a method either throws an exception or it does not

Well, almost no methods are like this;)  In general, a method throws an exception based on logic and conditions.  In your case, the exception will be thrown if verifyRoute==true *and* the route is invalid. I assume that the exception is *not* thrown if verifyRoute==true and the route is valid.

A @throws entry indicates that a method *can* throw a certain exception.  You are saying that when 
verifyRoute==false it does not throw that exception.  But in general, your method *can* throw that exception.  You might want to document that verifyRoute controls whether the method verifies the route and if false, prevents the InvalidRouteException exception.

Then again, relying on the caller to know whether the route is valid seems to be poor design.  You should re-work the classes/interfaces for optimized performance without the caller passing whether the route is known to be valid.